# Error execute webpack

Tags: api, symfony, vue.js

I'm developing a site with Symfony (Backend) and VueJs (Frontend) but when I run the build command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server --https --port 9000
```

I have an error like this:

> Running webpack-dev-server ...
>
> (node:6930) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
>   /Volumes/PROJETS/SITES/test/Application/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:14
>       throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
>       ^
>
> Error: Callback was already called.
>       at throwError (/Volumes/PROJETS/SITES/test/Application/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:14:11)
>       at /Volumes/PROJETS/SITES/test/Application/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2805:7
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:176:11)

Do you have an idea where the problem comes from? Thank you

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on .hooks instead ` is just a warning, the error is likely coming from your code catching the exception and executing the callback twice.

Comment: The problem is that nothing is started because of the error

Comment: Did this ever get solved I am having the same issue.